# Unnest JSON to SQL rows

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I'm trying to unnest a JSON column in SQL (bigquery) so that I can have multiple rows. I've been trying to search how to do this but I think I have a unique case here:

| id | json column |
| --- | --- |
| abc | {"callFee": 0, "estimationEx": {"estimatedAt": 12312312344}, "surgePolicyId": "v1-202101020126", "userVehicleId": "VRIVFLP2WK", "userRequestTags": ["NO_BYPASSING_ROUTE", "NO_UNKIND", "NO_TOO_MUCH_TALKER", "NO_UNCLEAN", "NO_WILD_DRIVING"]} |

I only want to parse the "userRequestTags" part and have the following output:

| id | UserRequest |
| --- | --- |
| abc | NO_BYPASSING_ROUTE |
| abc | NO_UNKIND |
| abc | NO_TOO_MUCH_TALKER |
| abc | NO_UNCLEAN |
| abc | NO_WILD_DRIVING |

I tried using the function JSON_QUERY but I don't think this will take me anywhere. Any ideas please? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below

```
select id, trim(tag, '"') as UserRequest
from `project.dataset.table`, 
unnest(json_extract_array(json_column, '$.userRequestTags')) tag
```

If applied to sample data in your questtion - output is

[image]